# Access ubuntu server on vmware through browser. I can ping but not open in browser

Tags: vmware

I can ping and ssh into the server just fine. But cannot open it in chrome or firefox after having moved it to new mac. My setup is vmware Fusion on Mountain Lion, running an ubuntu server.
Hosts file on mac:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

192.168.222.128    local.server.com
```

Ping works fine, but telnet fails:

```
$ telnet local.server.com
Trying 192.168.222.128...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.222.128: Connection refused
```

The vmware image is setup to use NAT. If I switch to Bridged nothing works, not even ping or ssh.

The ipctables in the image looks like this:

```
sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any ideas are very appreciated. Have looked everywhere for a solution to no prevail.

Comment: Is a webserver like Apache or nginx installed, running and listening on 192.168.222.128?

Comment: @TeunVink Write it as an answer and I will give you credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure a webserver like Apache or nginx installed, running and listening on 192.168.222.128.

Answer (score 0):

Umbutu and many other linux distributions do not install a telnet daemon by default, and telnet is strongly discouraged. use secure shell instead. if ssh is not installed it can be installed by running `sudo apt-get install ssh-server` on umbutu.

Comment: Maybe it's because I have misunderstood telnet. I don't need that though. WHat I need is for the server to respond to calling it from a browser in the host

Comment: In that case you need to telnet to port 80, not to the default telnet port.